# How to generate new back colour if two object's back colour match?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, random

I have a rather simple WCF program in which a user can click two buttons:
`ChangeBackGroundColour` & `ChangeButtonColour`.

The WCF service is returning a random colour from a list of colours, and that string is dictating the colour of the two objects via switch case statement.

However, the colour of the objects cannot be the same. How would one stop a duplicate?

Heres my code:

**Front_End**

```
public partial class Front_End : Form
{
    RandomColourServiceReference.RandomColoursServiceClient ws = null;
    string BackGroundColour { get; set; }
    string TextColour { get; set; }

    public Front_End()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Front_End_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ws = new RandomColourServiceReference.RandomColoursServiceClient();
    }

    private void BtnChangeBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackGroundColour = ws.GenerateRandomColour();
        switch (BackGroundColour)
        {
            case "Red":
                this.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case "Blue":
                this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
            case "Black":
                this.BackColor = Color.Black;
                break;
            case "Purple":
                this.BackColor = Color.Purple;
                break;
            case "Green":
                this.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void BtnChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextColour = ws.GenerateRandomColour();

        switch (TextColour)
        {
            case "Red":
                btnChangeButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
                btnChangeBack.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case "Blue":
                btnChangeButton.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                btnChangeBack.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
            case "Black":
                btnChangeButton.BackColor = Color.Black;
                btnChangeBack.BackColor = Color.Black;
                break;
            case "Purple":
                btnChangeButton.BackColor = Color.Purple;
                btnChangeBack.BackColor = Color.Purple;
                break;
            case "Green":
                btnChangeButton.BackColor = Color.Green;
                btnChangeBack.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**RandomColourService**

```
public class RandomColoursService : IRandomColoursService
{
    public string GenerateRandomColour()
    {
        //Declare and initialize a list of string colours
        List<String> colours = new List<String>();
        colours.AddRange(new String[]{ "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Pink", "Purple", "Black"});

        //create new instance of random
        Random rand = new Random();

        //return a random colour in array
        return colours[rand.Next(0, colours.Count)];
    }
}
```

**IRandomColourService**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRandomColoursService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GenerateRandomColour();
}
```

I have a feeling a while loop should be involved but I'm not quite sure.

Or maybe I should make 2 objects to return from wcf instead of just one and check if they are duplicate in wcf and generate a new one if they are?
So it's only ever going to send 2 different colours. Would that be best?

---

***Here's the updated code after trying to add more properties**

**Front_End**

```
public partial class Front_End : Form
{

    RandomColoursService.RandomColoursServiceClient ws = null;

    /*create two properties that can:385
    A. set the initial colours for the form objects. 
    B. be passed to wcf service as a used color to be removed from the list of colours that could potentially be returned next. */  
    Color BackGroundColour { get; set; } = Color.Blue;
    Color TextColour { get; set; } = Color.Red;
    Color ButtonColour { get; set; } = Color.Black;
    public Front_End()
    {
        //objects are initilized with colours. 
        InitializeComponent();
        btnChangeBack.BackColor = ButtonColour;
        btnChangeButton.BackColor = ButtonColour;
        btnChangeText.BackColor = ButtonColour;
        this.BackColor = BackGroundColour;
        lblTitle.ForeColor = TextColour;
        btnChangeBack.ForeColor = TextColour;
        btnChangeButton.ForeColor = TextColour;
        btnChangeText.ForeColor = TextColour;

    }

    private void Front_End_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create new instance of wcf service
        ws = new RandomColoursService.RandomColoursServiceClient();

    }

    private void BtnChangeBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This list is populated with the with current colours
        List<Color> UsedColours = new List<Color>() {TextColour, ButtonColour, BackGroundColour};
        //Call for another colour, pass in the current colour to be removed from list. 
        BackGroundColour = ws.GenerateRandomColour(UsedColours);
        //set object colour to returned colour
        this.BackColor = BackGroundColour;

    }

   private void BtnChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This list is populated with the with current colours
        List<Color> UsedColours = new List<Color>() {TextColour, BackGroundColour, ButtonColour};
        //Call for another colour, pass in the current colour to be removed from list. 
        ButtonColour = ws.GenerateRandomColour(UsedColours);
        //set object colour to returned colour
        btnChangeButton.BackColor = ButtonColour;
        btnChangeBack.BackColor = ButtonColour;
        btnChangeText.BackColor = ButtonColour;



    }

    private void BtnChangeText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This list is populated with the with current colours
        List<Color> UsedColours = new List<Color>() { BackGroundColour, ButtonColour, TextColour};
        //Call for another colour, pass in the current colour to be removed from list. 
        TextColour = ws.GenerateRandomColour(UsedColours);
        //set object colour to returned colour
        btnChangeButton.ForeColor = TextColour;
        btnChangeBack.ForeColor = TextColour;
        btnChangeText.ForeColor = TextColour;
        lblTitle.ForeColor = TextColour;

    }
}
}
```

**IRandomColoursService**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRandomColoursService
{
    [OperationContract]

    //As a parameter, pass in a list of coloured. 
    //The list will be populated with the current colours on the front end,
    //when a button is clicked a new call is made to wcf.
    Color GenerateRandomColour(List<Color> UsedColours);
}
}
```

**RandomColoursService**

```
    public class RandomColoursService : IRandomColoursService
{
    public Color GenerateRandomColour(List<Color> UsedColours)
    {
        //This is a list of potential colours that wcf can send. 
        List<Color> Colours = new List<Color>()
        {
            Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Black, Color.Green, Color.Indigo, Color.Orange
        };

        //This is a list of available colours once the current object colours are removed from the list.
        List<Color> AvailableColours = Colours.Except(UsedColours).ToList();
        Random rand = new Random();
        return Colours[rand.Next(0, AvailableColours.Count)];
    }


}
```

To clarify, I'm supposed to pass a list of UsedColours when I make a call to wcf. The UsedColors are deducted from the colours List and then an available colours list holds whats left. A single random Color from the available colours list should then be returned per call?

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***If your code can be modified (Interface included) these are the changes that I propose***:

Since you have two Properties that reference the selected Colors, you could assign default values and use these values to set the initial Colors of the Form and the Buttons.

These properties can then be used to reference an already used Color that can't be selected by the `GenerateRandomColour([Color])` method.
The Color parameter passed to method is removed from the list of Colors before randomly picking a new one:

---

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRandomColoursService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Color GenerateRandomColour(Color UsedColor);
}

public class RandomColoursService : IRandomColoursService
{
    public Color GenerateRandomColour(Color UsedColor)
    {
        List<Color> colours = new List<Color>() { 
            Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Pink, Color.Purple, Color.Black
        };
        colours.Remove(UsedColor);
        Random rand = new Random();
        return colours[rand.Next(0, colours.Count)];
    }
}
```

---

```
RandomColourServiceReference.RandomColoursServiceClient ws = null;

Color BackGroundColour { get; set; } = Color.Red;
Color TextColour { get; set; } = Color.Black;

public Front_End()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    btnChangeButton.BackColor = TextColour;
    btnChangeBack.BackColor = TextColour;
    this.BackColor = BackGroundColour;
}

private void BtnChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextColour = ws.GenerateRandomColour(BackGroundColour);
    btnChangeButton.BackColor = TextColour;
    btnChangeBack.BackColor = TextColour;
}

private void BtnChangeBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackGroundColour = GenerateRandomColour(TextColour);
    this.BackColor = BackGroundColour;
}
```

**Update**:
If you want to add more controls and related properties, change the `GenerateRandomColour` method, allowing it to accept a `List<Color>` instead of a single Color reference.
(The [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2)'s [Except()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Except%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) extension method is used here to filter a List using another)
For example:

```
public Color GenerateRandomColour(List<Color> UsedColor)
{
    List<Color> colours = new List<Color>() { 
        Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Pink, Color.Purple, Color.Black
    };
    List<Color> AvailableColours = colours.Except(UsedColor).ToList();
    Random rand = new Random();
    return AvailableColours[rand.Next(0, AvailableColours.Count)];
}
```

---

```
Color BackGroundColour { get; set; } = Color.Black;
Color TextColour { get; set; } = Color.Red;
Color AnotherColour { get; set; } = Color.Green;

private void BtnChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Color> UsedColors = new List<Color>() { BackGroundColour, AnotherColour };
    TextColour = ws.GenerateRandomColour(UsedColors);
    btnChangeButton.BackColor = TextColour;
    btnChangeBack.BackColor = TextColour;
}

//(...)
```

and so on.

This can get too cumbersome if there are many properties, though.
You could build a specialized class that maps Colors to Controls (using their references or their names) which is then used to exchange informations with the `GenerateRandomColour()` method.

Comment: Oh my. You can have a list or an array of Colors!? Thats good to know! I tried to expand and add a third property so theres a button to change background, buttons and text colour. I basically just added an extra parameter but **colours.Remove** can only be used with 1 argument. Any idea how to remove 2 items from the list? or can't it be done?

Comment: A List can contain anything. See the Update for a possible alternative method, if you need to change more properties. The `List.Except(List)` extension method is used here to filter a List using another.

Comment: I'm getting **"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Drawing.Color>' to 'System.Drawing.Color'"** for UsedColors on each of the button click methods on the Front End. I've updated the service reference but still getting the error. Gone through the code It's all List<Color> where it should be. Any Idea? Thanks Jimi.

Comment: Well, check it out again :) (comparing your code with the code in the update, I mean). It looks like your `GenerateRandomColour()` method is trying to return a `List<Color>` instead of a `Color`. Or something like this.

Comment: Ok, Jimi. How is this supposed to be? Feel like I've tried all the combinations. :P Though to be honest I say this to my tutor then she shows me I'm stupid. I've add an edit to the original code, if you'd be so kind!

Comment: Your code is OK. There's a minor bug in the updated code: `return Colours[rand.Next(0, AvailableColours.Count)];` should be `return AvailableColours[rand.Next(0, AvailableColours.Count)];`. This, however, just causes a wrong color selection (it allows a used color). Are you sure is there a correct mapping for the Service provider, `RandomColoursService`? You're calling it `RandomColoursServiceClient`, but I don't have this reference in the code. I only have `RandomColoursService.GenerateRandomColour()` as a known method of the class. Check this reference and see it has actually been updated.

Comment: Hi Jimi! I made a new program incase I screwed something up with the first one somehow but same error. Here's a link the GitHub repo, any chance you can take a look at some point? It's receiving a list of `usedcolours` its returning a single random item from `availableColours` as it should. I've made 3 other WCF programs for uni and they all have `NameServiceReference.nameServiceReferenceClient ws = null` and then `ws = new NameServiceReference.NameServiceReferenceClient()` Is that where you think the error is coming from? https://github.com/DavieB22/RandomColoursService1.0

Comment: I told you to update the references. In your `WinForms` Project `Front_End -> ConnectedService -> RandomColoursServiceReference` right-click and `Configure Service References`. In `Data Type -> Collection Type` change to  `System.Collection.Generic.List`. Your Service and your ForntEnd are using two different interfaces right now. You can see it in the Object Browser. The Front End one is expecting an Array of Colors as method parameter.

Comment: That did it! Before I just clicked update service reference. This is all really knew, it was only yesterday I found I could update. Before that I was just deleting and making a new :P Thanks Jimi!